# disable finish activity after intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

i have activity that contain RecyclerView when click on item in the Recycler start new activity , my problem is when back to the RecyclerView activity i need to display which item is clicked , so i have to stop finish for the RecyclerView Activity ,

NOTE : when user click in item i use image view show and hide to check item , when user click the image view is show , any idea ?

this is my RecyclerView adapter

```
    public class ScreenRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScreenRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    String image_list[];
    List<ImageView> items;
    String chiliSharedpreferences = "chiliSharedpreferences";

    public ScreenRecyclerAdapter(String[] image_list, Context context){
        super();
        this.image_list = image_list;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();}
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen_items, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;}
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.location_text_view.setText(image_list[position]);
        items.add(holder.check_image_view);

  }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return image_list.length;
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView check_image_view ;
        TextView location_text_view;
        LinearLayout linear;
        CardView loactionCardView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            check_image_view = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_image_view);
            location_text_view = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view);
            linear = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
            loactionCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            loactionCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MakeAllInvisbale();
                    check_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(chiliSharedpreferences, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
                    editor.putString("screenId","id1");

                    editor.commit();
                }
            });}}
    private void MakeAllInvisbale() {
        for(ImageView item : items) {
            item.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}}}
```

Comment: store your selected values in sharedpreference or any list (easier for multiple values), and in your activity's onresume() display the list with those selected values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save to `SharedPreferences` clicked view position

```
editor.putInt("SAVED_CLICKED_ITEM", getPosition());
```

and ckeck every time is position are saved, smth like this:

```
 SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(chiliSharedpreferences, MODE_PRIVATE);
 int position = shared.getInt("SAVED_CLICKED_ITEM", getPosition());
 if (position == getPosition()) {
     // do what you want
 }
```